Memu crashes on attempted launch: The core process of Memu has ended. Click OK to close the window
This virtual machine is important as it has whatsapp and some authentication apps on as my phone is quite old. Is it possible to regain the VM? I have Windows 10. Everything is fully updated. The last thing I did on MeMu was updatingg locations of shared folders.
I have tried exporting it, opening in virtualbox, opening in 7-zip. 7-zip revealed the most. export file->disk image->2.img is unreadable.
I have also tried re-installing and importing the .ova file. A new VM created works fine.
